# Viewing PDF Inside Browser - Broken in Chrome Using POST

Tags: html, node.js, google-chrome, pdf, http-headers

So I don't know when, but apparently there's been a change with Chrome that has broken viewing PDF's inside the browser.  Viewing these inside Firefox or IE work; this seems to be a Chrome-only issue.

As of now, how I'm doing it is like this.  Users POST data to the server, which does some magic with PDF population, and sends the PDF back to the browser.  We're using the `Content-Disposition`, `Content-Length`, and `Content-Type` headers (I'm assuming) correctly:

```
Content-Disposition: "inline; filename=\"some-pdf.pdf\""
Content-Length: "1860799"
Content-Type: "application/pdf"
```

Is there any specific reason why Chrome refuses to load these files using the in-browser PDF viewer?

## EDIT:

It seems as though Chrome doesn't load inline files when POSTing to a server.

Working Example:

```
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');

var app = express();

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('Listening on http://localhost:3000');
});

app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  fs.stat('./some-pdf.pdf', function(e, stats) {
    if(e) throw e;

    var stream = fs.createReadStream( './some-pdf.pdf' );

    res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'inline; filename="some-pdf.pdf"');
    res.setHeader('Content-Length', stats.size);
    res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/pdf');

    stream.pipe(res);
  });
});
```

Non-Working Example:

```
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');

var app = express();

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('Listening on http://localhost:3000');
});

app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('<form method="POST"><input type="submit", value="Get PDF"></form>');
});

app.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
  fs.stat('./some-pdf.pdf', function(e, stats) {
    if(e) throw e;

    var stream = fs.createReadStream( './some-pdf.pdf' );

    res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'inline; filename="some-pdf.pdf"');
    res.setHeader('Content-Length', stats.size);
    res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/pdf');

    stream.pipe(res);
  });
})
```

Comment: After a bit of research, it seems as though Chrome refuses to load inline files with POST requests...  Editing the answer to reflect what I've found.

Answer (score 1):

It's a Chrome PDF Viewer bug. When you try to save the PDF, sometimes the plug-in re-request the page to be saved. If it's a HTTP Post, there is an internal error and the save fails.

It can be seen here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=224520

Comment: This has been working for me after a Chrome update, though I've not re-run the above code to verify.  This might also depend on how you handle repeated requests on the server level though.